# Converting geodatabase into Geopackage in FME

Tags: file-geodatabase, fme-form, geopackage

I have never used FME and need to convert some geodatabase files into Geopackages. So the data can be stored in a GeoServer and published online.

Answer (score 0):

Using FME workbench the simplest approach is:
*Assumption is geodatabase source is polygon geometry in this case.

FME reader **(File Geodatabase - Open API)**

and a FME Writer **Geopackage** and set a table name.
and also switch the geometry type to geopackage polygon.

You may want to add more attributes (or remove them). that will require more transformers.

[image]